# Grouping by 2 columns while using a default value for missing rows in set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `items` table that looks like this:

```
date        category_id  value ...
----------  -----------  -----
2019-01-01  1            2
2019-01-01  1            3
2019-01-01  2            3
2019-01-03  1            5
```

I want to group these items by `date` and `category_id`, while summing the `value` column. Not every date is present and category_ids are missing on other dates.

Any combination of date and category_id that is missing should be set to `0`. The result should look like this:

```
date        category_id  value
----------  -----------  -----
2019-01-01  1            5
2019-01-01  2            3
2019-01-02  1            0
2019-01-02  2            0
2019-01-03  1            5
2019-01-03  2            0
```

I have a query that can fill in missing dates, but not missing category_ids:

```sql
SELECT
  d.day::date,
  i.category_id,
  COALESCE(SUM(i.value), 0) AS value
FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(MIN(items.date), MAX(items.date), '1 day') d
  FROM items
) d(day)
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.date = d.day
GROUP BY d.day, i.category_id
ORDER BY d.day ASC, i.category_id ASC
```

This gives the following result:

```
date        category_id  value
----------  -----------  -----
2019-01-01  1            5
2019-01-01  2            3
2019-01-02               0
2019-01-03  1            5
```

How do I extend this query to also include the missing category_ids?

All the category_ids can be retrieved from the `items` table itself, but there's also a `categories` table with an `id` column if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the values:

```
SELECT d.day::date, c.category_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.value), 0) AS value
FROM (SELECT generate_series(MIN(i.date), MAX(i.date), '1 day') as day
      FROM items i
     ) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT category_id from items) c LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i.date = d.day AND i.category_id  c.category_id
GROUP BY d.day, c.category_id
ORDER BY d.day ASC, i.category_id ASC;
```

Note:  You may have another source for categories (say a `categories` table) and you can use that instead.